# Headers repeat issue after every 100 rows in phpmy admin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Headers repeat after every 100 rows in phpmyadmin even I disabled the option from setting the issue is not resolve. Can anybody give the right solution of this issue as I am not finding any?

Comment: Did you change the setting in the Settings tab of phpMyAdmin or in the configuration file `config.inc.php`? What was the exact setting you used or configuration line you put in the file?

Comment: From setting tab I have changed

Comment: @IsaacBennetch can u help plz

Comment: I f we go and change things from setting they are now working and implimenting what we need to do?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce the problem you're having; when I set the value to 0 in the settings tab or the configuration file it seems to be honored correctly. Can you look in your `phpmyadmin` database at the `pma__userconfig` table and see if there is a row corresponding to your user account?